# Need help to sorting an array in a complicated way c# linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a strict similar to this :

```
struct Chunk
 {
   public float d; // distance from player
   public bool active; // is it active
 }
```

I have an array of this struct.

What I need:

I need to sort it so the first element is an inactive chunk that is also the furthest from the player, than the next element is active and is also the closest to the player and that is the pattern,

1. Inactive, furthest
2. Active, closest
3. Inactive, furthest
4. Active, closest
5. Inactive, furthest
   And so on...

Currently I'm using LINQ,
And I'm doing this :

```
chunk = chunk.AsParallel().OrderBy(x => x.active ? x.d : -x.d).ToArray();
```

But I don't know how to make it alternate one after another.

Comment: Try using `OrderBy(x => !x.active ? -x.d : x.d).ThenBy(x.active ? x.d : -x.d)` to sort on multiple fields.

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you have 10 active elements and only 2 inactive?

Comment: The `unity3d` tag isn't really necessary but thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I don't know how to make it alternate one after another.

If you sort the array so that all the inactives are at the start, descending and all the actives are at the end, descending..

```
OrderBy(x => x.active?1:0).ThenBy(x=>-x.d)
```

then you can take an item from the start, then an item from the end, then from the start + 1, then the end - 1 working your way inwards

```
public static IEnumerable<Chunk> Interleave(this Chunk[] chunks){
  
    for(int s = 0, e = chunks.Length - 1; s<e;){

        if(!chunks[s].active)
            yield return chunks[s++]; 

        if(chunks[e].active)
            yield return chunks[e--];

    }

}
```

There's a bit in this so let's unpack it. This is an extension method that acts on an array of chunk. It's a custom enumerator method, so you'd call foreach on it to use it

```
foreach(var c in chunk.Interleave())
```

It contains a for loop that tracks two variables, one for the start index and one for the end. The start increments and the end decrements. At some point they'll meet and `s` will no longer be less than `e`, which is when we stop:

```
for(int s = 0, e = chunks.Length - 1; s<e;){
```

We need to look at the chunk before we return it, if it's an inactive near the start, `yield return` it and bump the start on by one. `s++` increments `s`, but resolves to the value `s` was before it incremented. It's thus conceptually like doing `chunks[s]; s += 1;` but in a one liner

```
if(!chunks[s].active)
    yield return chunks[s++];
```

Then we look at the chunk near the end, if it's `active` then return the ending one and bump the end index down

The inactive chunks are tracked by `s`, and if `s` reaches an active chunk it stops returning (every pass of the loop it is skipped), which means `e` will work its way down towards `s` returning only the actives

Similarly if there are more inactives than actives, `e` will stop decrementing first and `s` will work its way up towards `e`

---

If you never came across `yield return` before think of it as a way to allow you to resume from where you left off rather than starting the method over again. It's used with enumerations to provide a way for the enumeration to return an item, then be moved on one and return the next item. It works a bit like saving your game and going doing something else, then coming back, realising your save game and carrying on from where you left off. Asking an enumerator for Next makes it load the game, play a bit, then save and stop.. Then you Next again and the latest save id loaded, play some more, save and stop. This way you gradually get through the game a bit at a time. If you started a new enumeration by calling Interleave again, that's like starting a new game over from the beginning

MSDN will get [more detailed on yield return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) if you want to dig in more

---

Edit:

You can perform an in-place sort of your Chunk[] by having a custom comparer:

```
public class InactiveThenDistancedDescending : IComparer
{
   public int Compare(object x, object y)
   {
       var a = (Chunk)x;
       var b = (Chunk)y;
       if(a.Active == b.Active)
         return -a.Distance.CompareTo(b.Distance);
       else
         return a.Active.CompareTo(b.Active);
   }
}
```

And:

```
Array.Sort(chunkArray, _someInstanceOfThatComparerAbove);
```

Comment: I like this, and it also seems pretty fast, THANKS

Comment: Also how can I learn more about sorting stuff in this way? it sounds very interesting.

Comment: And one more thing.. Does adding AsParallel() do anything? and if it does, where should I add it?

Comment: Welcome! I don't know whether there is anything out there that teaches this; I expect so - I didn't set out to demo the use of anything in particular - I was just musing on a way to do as much as possible with an array and doing a custom interleaving iterator with `yield return` seemed like a reasonable teaching point! You might actually get another performance boost by switching to using Array.Sort and sorting the original chunks array in place rather than making a new array with the OrderBy.ToArray. As for Parallel, it might make things worse - you'd have to perf test it and see

Comment: I've noticed that my "game" runs a silky smooth 60 fps normally, but I can see in Unity's builtin profiler tool that, at about the time the array is sorted the time to render the frames jumps up by around 200 percent or more for about a few frames,  but I'm sure that only because I have a await task.yield in between my sort methods which also take a few frames due to the awaiting, but I'm more worried about the memory allocation by those methods.

Comment: I don't really want memory being allocated while the game is running, and I'd rather it be allocated during the loading screen for the world, which is where I allocate all the memory required for everything currently. So, is there any way I could provide LINQ with memory that's already been allocated or is there a way to save the memory that's been allocated after the first LINQ methods have been ran and reuse that same memory?

Comment: Great answer Caius. I would suggest if the O.P. is unfamiliar with `yield return` maybe link to an existing Q&A

Comment: @Shiv so does it mean that the array you give to .OrderBy can be a fixed thing per player? You will change the contents of it but not need to  renew it? In that case it might make sense to use Array.Sort to sort the existing array in place, rather than running linq OrderBy.ToArray which will take the existing data, sort it, allocate a new array and copy the data into it and then the Interleave enumerates that new one.. I'll take a look at it later if you don't message back saying you've sorted something :)

Comment: Yeah so what's actually happening is that I am running a compute shader which give me an array with the same length everytime I dispatch it, and then, I do all the fancy sorting on that array. And my current circumstances make it so the compute shader is dispatched every 2/3 secs at max.

Comment: @CaiusJard Hey, I got back to working on this chunk rendering system and I have an idea to make the loading a little better and faster. The things is that when I get this array of chunk states, most of the chunks actually will never exist, but they have to be a part of the calculation. So in the foreach loop the idea is to skip those non-existent chunks if we come across it, but I can't put that information in the Chunk class due to how I'm calculating their states, so the solution I guess is to pass in a "ref bool loaded" and "ref bool unloaded" but thats illegal in C#, 1/2

Comment: so I tried to pass in a class that has the 2 bools as public, but that didn't work, and i also tried to make a class static and have it hold variables which in it self is a bad idea but it still didn't work, so how can I "pass" in parameters into the Interleave method? and when I call this method it actually lasts for multiple frames too so idk if that causes other problems.

Comment: There's nothing really magical about an extension method; it's just a normal static method that the compiler allows you to call in a differennt order. You could just as easily do `Interleave(myChunkArray)` as `myChunkArray.Interleave()` - you write the latter, the compiler makes it the former. If you add more arguments, e.g. `Interleave(this Chunk[] chunks, bool x, bool y)` then you'd call it like `myChunkArray.Interleave(true, false)` or `Interleave(myChunkArray, true, false)` - the first argument having `this` simply means it can be called as if it were a method of a `Chunk[]`, but it's not

Comment: ps; I added a comparer/sort strategy that may avoid you having to make new arrays all the time with LINQ's ToArray

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you want to split this into two lists, sort them, then interleave them.

```
var inactive = chunk.Where(x => !x.active).OrderByDescending(x => x.d);
var active = chunk.Where(x => x.active).OrderBy(x => x.d);
var interleaved = inactive.Zip(active, (a, b) => new [] { a, b }).SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: It seems to have broken my rendering system, because the chunks stopped unloading. LOL

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can do it with only one line of code.

I wrote a method that would only require the Array to be sorted once. Then, it enters either the next closest or furthest chunk based on the current index of the for loop (odd = closest, even = furthest). I remove the item from the sorted list to ensure that it will not be reentered in the results list. Finally, I return the results as an Array.

```
public Chunk[] SortArray(List<Chunk> list_to_sort)
{
    //Setup Variables
    var results = new List<Chunk>();
    int count = list_to_sort.Count;

    //Tracking the sorting list so that we only need to sort the list once
    list_to_sort = list_to_sort.OrderBy(x => x.active).ThenBy(x => x.d).ToList();

    //Loop through the list
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        results.Add(list_to_sort[i % 2 == 0 ? list_to_sort.Count - 1 : 0]);
        list_to_sort.RemoveAt(i % 2 == 0 ? list_to_sort.Count - 1 : 0);
    }

    // Return Results
    return results.ToArray();
}
```

There is probably a better way of doing this but hopefully it helps. Please note that I did not test this method.

Comment: I suspect you meant to sort by `x.active` first, then by `x.d` instead of the other way around. Also, what happens to this method if the number of active entries is not equal to the number of inactive entries?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson You are right, I've updated my answer. 

You also bring up a good point and it depends how they want to handle it. As of right now, let say there are 3 extra Active chunks in the list, it will insert it as (closest, furthest, closest).

Comment: My frame rate just goes to 0 for a few secs...